# Problem Copying IIS7 Site for Testing

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I have copied an IIS 7 site's files to a new directory, created a new site for copied files in IIS 7, set up bindings that aren't conflicting, configured the copied site to use a different database than the production site.

I can go to the login page of the copied site. The login page can authenticate me, but when it redirects me to a subdirectory, I get a 500 error from the server. I cannot figure out why I can't access these subdirectories.

Any ideas? This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

It was a classic ASP problem.

I turned failed request tracing on, and saw this:

```
LineNumber 24
ErrorCode ASP 0131 
Description Disallowed Parent Path
```

So I went to line 24 in the problem file:

```
<!--    #include file = "../public.asp" -->
```

I looked up the error code. The problem was that Parent Paths was not enabled for ASP on the site.

Eureka!

Comment: Don't forget though that parent paths are considered a security vulnerability, which is why they are turned off by default now. If you have any sort of automated security assessment happening, this will be caught and reported.

Answer (score 0):

To see the error use IE on the server, and under advanced internet options switch off Friendly HTTP Errors. This should give you a more readable ASP.Net error which you can troubleshoot further.